# Optimization problem in the standard form

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Let $x\rightarrow x^{T}c$ be an objective function of an optimization problem in the standard form, for which the optimal solution doesn't exist. Does then exist an optimal solution to $x\rightarrow x^{T}(-c)$?

Comment: Not necessarily. Imagine a program with no valid $x$. Such a program never has an optimal solution (for any objective function).

Comment: can you tell me more about that? I'm kinda new to this topic. Thank you. Maybe you can post an answer.

Comment: I have now tried to find concrete programs for the various cases. Feel free to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have an unconstrained problem with objective $x^Tc$ we have no optimum because we can get "as good as we want": Chose $x_n = -nc$ to obtain a sequence of values $-n\|c\| \to-\infty$. If we are constrained, the admissible region is a polytope of the form $Ax = b$:
$$\min_{Ax=b, x\ge 0} x^T c \tag P$$
If the admissible region $\{Ax=b, x\ge 0\}$ is bounded and non-empty, we always have a solution, no matter what $c$ we chose (esp. $-c$ also gives a solution). If it's empty, we never have a solution and if it's unbounded we can give examples such that (P) is unbounded for both $c, -c$, bounded for exactly one of $c,-c$ or bounded for both $c$ and $-c$, so we can't really say anything.

Examples:
$A = \pmatrix{1&0}, b = 0, c = \pmatrix{0\\1}$: unbounded for $-c$, unique for $c$
$A = \pmatrix{1&0}, b = 1, c = \pmatrix{1\\0}$: solutions for both, $c, -c$
$A = \pmatrix{1&0&-1&0\\0&-1&0&1}, b = \pmatrix{1\\1}, c=\pmatrix{1\\1\\0\\0}$: unbounded for both $c, -c$